# Expanding Abbrev Mode Alphabet

Tags: abbrev, numbers

Is it possible to write some elisp code so that we can use numbers for Abbrev Mode abbreviations? E.g.,

m2 -> me too
h4 -> hope for
gr8 -> greate

Comment: On second thought, this might not be a good idea, so, it can be closed, if desired so. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "h4" "hope for")
```

if you really want an h4, you just "undo" (for me that is C-/, but you may have it bound to something else.) You can also limit the scope to a specific mode, e.g. `org-mode-abbrev-table` or so.